# Mostrar datos de otra tabla filtrando por el ID en una consulta

Tags: mysql, sql

Mi problema es el siguiente, tengo las siguientes tablas

Tabla Ciudades

[image: TablaCiudades]

Tabla Conductores

[image: TablaConductores]

Tabla rutas

[image: TablaRutas]

Y órdenes de ruta
[image: Ordenes de ruta]

Básicamente estoy tratando de realizar una consulta en donde me muestre los viajes que ha realizado el conductor con `IdConductor` '134567890', lo estoy haciendo por medio de la siguiente sentencia:

```sql
select   Nombre1, Nombre2, Apellido1, Apellido2, CiudadOrigen, CiudadDestino
from conductores, ordenesderuta,rutas
where IdConductor = '134567890'
and ordenesderuta.Ruta = rutas.IdRuta
and conductores.IdConductor = ordenesderuta.Conductor
```

Y me da como resultado:

| Nombre1 | Nombre2 | Apellido1 | Apellido2 | CiudadOrigen | CiudadDestino |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jaime | NULL | Rojas | Barrera | CD00000004 | CD00000002 |
| Jaime | NULL | Rojas | Barrera | CD00000005 | CD00000003 |

Y está bien, eso es lo que quiero que muestre, pero básicamente lo que necesito es que cuando se realice esa consulta, en lugar de mostrar allí en `ciudadorigen` y `ciudaddestino` con el `IdCiudad`, me lo muestre con el nombre. He tratado de varias formas y la verdad es que no he podido, me gustaría saber si se puede o debido a tantas tablas se complicaría.

Comment: ¿Necesitás mostrar el nombre de la ciudad? Te falta hacer el select de la primera tabla que mencionás.

Comment: Tu consulta requiere el uso de JOIN, puedes ver cómo en [Ejemplos de SQL inner join](https://codigosql.com/ejemplos/ejemplos-de-sql-inner-join/)

Answer (score 2):

Para obtener el resultado que esperas, tendrías que incorporar la tabla `Ciudades` en la consulta mediante un doble `JOIN`, uno para la ciudad origen y otro para la ciudad destino.

Voy a hacerlo mediante `JOIN` explícito, porque las consultas quedan más claras así que con `JOIN` implícito, como lo tienes en tu código original.

```
SELECT   
    co.Nombre1, 
    co.Nombre2, 
    co.Apellido1, 
    co.Apellido2, 
    oc.Nombre AS CiudadOrigen, 
    dc.Nombre AS CiudadDestino
FROM conductores AS co, 
    INNER JOIN ordenesderuta AS or ON co.IdConductor = or.Conductor 
    INNER JOIN rutas ru ON or.Ruta = ru.IdRuta
    INNER JOIN ciudades oc ON ru.CiudadOrigen  = oc.IdCiudad
    INNER JOIN ciudades dc ON ru.CiudadDestino = dc.IdCiudad
WHERE co.IdConductor = '134567890';
```

Comment: Hola, porque hacer dos join a la tabla ciudades, no bastaría con uno?

Comment: Hola @Japv no, no bastaría con un `JOIN`, hay una ciudad de origen y otra de destino, por tanto, para cada una es necesario un `JOIN`.

Comment: Ok, gracias ......